# Сессия и форма PHP

Tags: php, сессия

недавно возникла проблема с сессиями пользователя.
Авторизованный пользователь имеет $_SESSION['id'], он не меняется, но как мне сделать, если человек отправил форму, но 2 раз он отправить сможет только через час допустим. Можете пожалуйста кинуть пример? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: при отправке формы записываете в сессию время отправки. потом проверяете прошел час или нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = "2";


if (......) { // если форма была отправлена, устанавливаем в сессию время истечения блокировки (+1 час от текущего)
    $limit_time = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+1 hour'));
    $_SESSION['limit_time'] = $limit_time;
}

// далее проверка при попытке повторной отправки

if ( strtotime(date("d.m.Y H:s")) > strtotime($_SESSION['limit_time']) ) {
    echo 'Время блокировки вышло, можно отправить форму еще раз';
} else {
    echo 'Все еще блокируем, время блокировки не вышло';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Сессии нельзя использовать для каких-либо ограничений.

чтобы запретить пользователю делать что-либо, нужно использовать базу данных

Comment: Хорошо, уточню, при отправке формы, отправлять в БД текущую дату, и в скрипте проверять прошел ли час с нее, или нет, если нет, то не пускать на форму, верно?

Comment: ну можно и не пускать на форму, но главное проверять время при обработке формы